# VSCode shows pending changes from another branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I started using VSCode's built-in version control feature recently. I made changes to two files while I was in a given branch (let's call it `bug-39`) and then switched to another one (let's say `bug-40`) with `git checkout bug-40`.

When I re-launched VSCode afterwards, I verified I was in `bug-40` (in the bottom left corner of the screen) but the pending changes section still listed the two files I had modified while in `bug-39`.

Is this normal, or perhaps I did something wrong and didn't save the files in `bug-39` but instead "globally"?

Comment: did you commit in `bug-39`?

Comment: No, I saved the changes but did not commit in `bug-39`. I guess that was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `git commit` before switching branch.

The changes are then "carried" to the new branch, so that you may commit them there.

> Is this normal, or perhaps I did something wrong and didn't save the
> files in bug-39 but instead "globally"?

In the end, this is normal. You didn't do anything *wrong*, just something not intended. There is no such concept in git as "saved globally".